# The closed and bounded sets are compact in the product topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^{\aleph_0}$ with the product topology, it is true that all the closed and bounded (in the uniform sense) sets are compact?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the uniform sense"? In some metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every closed subset that is bounded in the uniform metric is contained in some product of closed intervals $\prod{[a_i,b_i]}$, hence it is compact.