# Characterization of compact sets in the product space $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Taking into account that $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is a metrizable space with the metric $D(x,y)=\sup\{\overline{d}(x_i,y_i)/i: i\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$, where $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots), y=(y_1,y_2,\dots)$ and $\overline{d}(a,b)=\min\{|b-a|,1\}$. I'm trying to prove the following characterization for compact sets in the product space $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$:

A set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is compact if and only if $K$ is closed and bounded.

My attempt:

The reverse direction can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038791/the-closed-and-bounded-sets-are-compact-in-the-product-topology). For the other direction, I notice that being $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ the product of Haussdorf spaces, then It is Hausdorff. So, compact sets are closed. I'm having trouble proving that compact sets are also bounded. I've tried the following. If $K\subset \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is a compact set, then notice that $K\subset \bigcup_{x\in K} B_D(x,\frac{1}{2})$, where $B_D$ means the open ball with respect to the metric $D$. So, there are $x_1,\dots,x_n\in K$ such that, $K\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_D(x_i,\frac{1}{2})$. Can I use that to get $K$ is bounded? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note $D(x,y) \le 1$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R^\omega$, so the whole space is bounded.  But $R^\omega$ is not compact.  What you need is not "bounded" but "totally bounded" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space

Comment: Thanks for your observations. So, what I'm trying to prove is not true? I mean, in this space, $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$, compact sets are not necessarily bounded and closed?

Comment: Compact sets are bounded and closed, but not conversely. Some bounded closed sets are not compact.

Comment: I see. However, In this case, I founded this proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038791/the-closed-and-bounded-sets-are-compact-in-the-product-topology. That's why I think in this case bounded closed sets are compact. What do you think?

Comment: Notice that his notion of bounded is not the same as yours.  "bounded in the uniform sense"  is not boundedness for your metric.

Comment: $A \subseteq (X,d)$ is compact iff it's closed and totally bounded holds for all *complete* metric spaces $(X,d)$ and your metric on $\Bbb R^\omega$ is complete, so it follows from this general fact.